# Removing SQL invalid chars Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, xml-parsing, invalid-characters

I'm trying to remove a square box char from a column that is being used to populate xml's
The problem is the xmls aren't being created correctly, and are creating a lot of work for me. 
so as a scripted job each dayb I'm going to try to run sql to update the values to remove the offending char.

so far I have

```
select * from (select dump(narration) as dn,narration from ar_journal)
where dn like '%27%'
and dn not like '%=27:%';
```

This finds the offending stuff, but I'm wondering if it'd be possible to call the dn using a replace function?

note the dn is a dump of the column narration.

results are like the below
DN
Typ=1 Len=200: 96,27,97,110,115,102,101,114,32,102,114,111,109,32,67,117,115,116,111,109,101,114,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,57,48,48,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32

Narration
*CharWasHere*'ransfer from Customer 900
The values are unpredictable but the char is always the same,

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: Oracle supports regular expressions.  That seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(narration, chr(27)) from table
```

Comment: Thanks a million Egor, do you know of a way that I could select a number of these chars at once? i.e. if chr(27), chr(28), chr(60), chr(62) were all causing errors?

Comment: @BenCoughlan - `regexp_replace(replace(narration, chr(0)),'['||chr(1)||'-'||chr(31)||'<>]')`